# Could I turn a bass guitar into a large ukulele?

Tags: bass-guitar, ukulele

I'm a massive fan of having larger ukuleles and therefore if I got a bass guitar and replaced the strings and tuned it to a ukuleles standard tuning, would I have a working ukulele ?

Comment: How do you define "working ukelele"?  With bass strings, you'd have a bass with an alternate tuning that would allow you to finger shapes the same way as with a ukelele -- are you replacing the strings with something else?

Comment: You already have the tuning of what is known as a contrabass ukulele (I hadn't heard of it, either): E1, A1, D2, G2.  However, I suspect that isn't what you had in mind.  The typical ukulele is a couple of octaves higher and is tuned somewhat like the higher four strings of a guitar, with one string shifted up an octave (e.g., the concert ukulele is G4, C4, E4, A4).  I have doubts about one's ability to get that high on a bass guitar scale with standard strings.